# gwt:run-codeserver not seeing code updates for referenced libraries on browser refresh, needs maven install

Tags: gwt, maven-3, gwt-super-dev-mode

Is it possible to make gwt:run-codeserver goal(from org.codehaus.mojo/gwt-maven-plugin) run with sources from referenced dependencies.

For a war project projA which depends on libA, it will add the sources of projA but for libA, it will add the source jar instead of the source folder to GWT source.
Because of this, it's not possible to have CodeServer recompile the code on browser refresh. I have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Mojo's Plugin for GWT wasn't designed for reactor builds. There are workarounds using the build-helper-maven-compiler to add the library sources to the war within a profile that you'd use for development; but the easiest and cleanest is to use the [`net.ltgt.gwt.maven: gwt-maven-plugin`](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin) instead (disclaimer: I'm the author, and former maintainer of the Mojo plugin). Have a look at my https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for examples of use.